# docker(1.5.1) artifactory (3.x) registry management

Tags: docker, artifactory

- The docker registry has gotten huge pretty quickly, is there a way to clean up the registry?
- Is there a way to combine all the dependent layers, I'd like to cut down on how long it takes to download an image
- Is there a way to pull a specific dependent layer:

> 8b44529354f3: Download complete
>
> 8b9b56bb19d4: Download complete
>
> 79b1e69a4835: Download complete

- Can you revert a docker push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems as interview questions. Interesting.

Can't answer all of them, but try to answer some of them. Will update later if have better solution.

> The docker registry has gotten huge pretty quickly, is there a way to clean up the registry?

Need be done by scripting currently.

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/pull/409

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/706

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry/issues/523

> Is there a way to combine all the dependent layers, I'd like to cut down on how long it takes to download an image

update later.

> Is there a way to pull a specific dependent layer:

No, I can't find the way. If someone knows how to do, let me know.

> Can you revert a docker push?

Some one answered it in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/docker-user/wNHzbFv7cDw

That’s one of the real strengths of Docker: the ability to go back to a previous commit. The secret is simply to `docker tag` the image you want.

Here’s an example. In this example, I first installed ping, then committed, then installed curl, and committed that. Then I rolled back the image to contain only ping:

```
$ docker history imagename
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY                SIZE
f770fc671f11        12 seconds ago      apt-get install -y curl   21.3 MB
28445c70c2b3        39 seconds ago      apt-get install ping      11.57 MB
8dbd9e392a96        7 months ago                                  131.5 MB

$ docker tag 2844 imagename   # <-- that's the secret right there

$ docker history imagename
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY             SIZE
28445c70c2b3        56 seconds ago      apt-get install ping   11.57 MB
8dbd9e392a96        7 months ago                               131.5 MB
```